# WordEditor remove blank lines at end of document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, word-addins

I am trying to detect and remove blank lines present in a specific range of a document using the below code:

```
    Document doc = appointmentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
    Bookmark bmkFound = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item("bmkToClean");
    Range bmkFound = bmkFound.Range;
    Find find = bmkFound.Find;
    find.Text = "\r";
    find.Replacement.Text = "";
    find.Execute();
    find.Text = "\r\n";
    find.Replacement.Text = "";
    find.Execute();
    find.Text = Convert.ToChar(13).ToString();
    find.Replacement.Text = "";
    find.Execute();
    find.Text = Convert.ToChar(10).ToString();
    find.Replacement.Text = "";
    find.Execute();

    lastChar.Text.Replace(Convert.ToChar(13), '');
    lastChar.Text.Replace(Convert.ToChar(10), '');
    lastChar.Text.Replace("\r", "");
    lastChar.Text.Replace("\n", "");
```

Nothing worked out so far. Any hint?

Comment: Did you try to debug the code going through each line step-by-step?

Comment: Yes. No error but no replacement :-/

Comment: The lines with \r and \n  can be removed from the code sample - these would find only that literal text. I would expect the 13 and 10 to work, as far as *finding* goes. If you comment out the replace stuff at the end, and add a `find.Select();` is a 13 or 10 selected at the end? If yes, then change the replacing to: `find.Replacement.Text = "";` and put it *before* the `Execute`. Note that this still probably doesn't do *exactly* what you need, but should confirm *how* to find/replace paragraph marks / end-of-line characters.

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks for your answer. the find.Select() function does not exist in C#.

Comment: According to the code in the question `find` is a `Range`, so `find.Select();` would have to work. `Find.Select();` however would not.

Comment: Hi Cindy, again the find.Select() may exist in VBA but not in C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, the issue was that I had several blank lines so the code needed the below adjustment:

```
Document doc = appointmentItem.GetInspector.WordEditor as 
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
Bookmark bmkFound = doc.Bookmarks.get_Item("bmkToClean");
Range bmkFound = bmkFound.Range;
Find find = bmkFound.Find;
find.Text = "\r";
find.Replacement.Text = "";
find.Forward = true;
find.Wrap = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
find.Replacement.Text = "";
find.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
```